# WCF service wrapper - passing endpointConfigurationName to service client constructor

Tags: c#, wcf

I have following wrapper to help me manage the wcf client lifetime:

```
public class ServiceProxyHelper<TProxy, TChannel> : IDisposable
      where TProxy : ClientBase<TChannel>, new()
      where TChannel : class
   {
      private TProxy m_proxy;

      public TProxy Proxy
      {
         get
         {
            if (m_proxy != null)
            {
               return m_proxy;
            }
            throw new ObjectDisposedException("ServiceProxyHelper");
         }
      }

      protected ServiceProxyHelper()
      {
         m_proxy = new TProxy();
      }

      public void Dispose()
      {
          //....
      }
}
```

I'm using that in the following way:

```
   public class AccountServiceClientWrapper : ServiceProxyHelper<AccountServiceClient, IAccountService>
   {
   }

   public class Test()
   {
      using(AccountServiceClientWrapper wrapper = new AccountServiceClientWrapper())
      {
         wrapper.Proxy.Authenticate();
      }
   }
```

How I can modify that code to provide **endpointConfigurationName** for the client ?

```
wrapper.Proxy.Endpoint.Name = "MyCustomEndpointName";
```

Is not working. That **endpointConfigurationName** should be provider to service client constructor, but how I can do that using this wrapper ?

Regards

Comment: Are you trying to change this at runtime or is this a static endpoint name for each instance of the helper?

Comment: This will be configured once for the helper instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) to create the proxy instance passing endpointConfigurationName as a parameter. For example,

```
protected ServiceProxyHelper(string endpointConfigurationName )
{
  m_proxy = (TProxy)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TProxy), endpointConfigurationName);
}
```

This will be an additional constructor in your wrapper to allow passing end point config name. Only flaw would be in case proxy type does not support such constructor, you will get an runtime exception instead of compile time error.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for specifying the instance of `TProxy` in the `ServiceProxyHelper` constructor.

```
protected ServiceProxyHelper(TProxy proxy)
{
  m_proxy = proxy;
}
```

Then, your proxy wrapper class would look like this:

```
public class AccountServiceClientWrapper : ServiceProxyHelper<AccountServiceClient, IAccountService>
{
private endpointCfgName = "{endpoint_here}";

public AccountServiceClientWrapper(): base(new AccountServiceClient(endpointCfgName))
        {
            //this.Proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "XYZ";
            //this.Proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "XYZ";
        }
}
```

And then, the way you use it remains completely the same.

Of course, you need to remove the `"new"` keyword from the TProxy definition